# GoDaddy: RewriteCond in .htaccess not working with "beginning of the line" (^)

Tags: htaccess, godaddy

I have `.htaccess` containing `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`.

It used to work just fine (it's been a long time since I last checked), but now it has stopped working. I have narrowed it down to the following example.

Suppose I want to redirect `www.mydomain.com/foo` but not when `foo` occurs anywhere else; so, for example, don't redirect if the URI is `/abc/foo`, `/abcfoo`, or `/foobar`.

Here is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/foo$
RewriteRule  .  /redirect.html  [last,redirect=temp]
```

I have tried changing `^/foo$` in various ways, but I can't get this to work.

The following all work as expected:

```
foo         Redirects wherever foo appears, e.g. /abcfoobar
foo$        Redirects whenever foo appears at the end, e.g. /abc/defoo
/foo        Redirects whenever /foo appears, e.g. /abc/foobar
/foo$       Redirects whenever /foo appears at the end, e.g. /abc/foo
```

The following always return *404 Not found*, no matter what I put as the URI.

```
^foo
^/foo
^/foo$
```

I don't know what's going on.

Please help me fix this. In case it helps, I'm using GoDaddy hosting.

Comment: Just as a test to see what `%{REQUEST_URI}` actually contains, you could try something like: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test` `RewriteRule . /test%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]` - What does it (try to) redirect to? Specifically, what is after "/test"?

Comment: @w3d I've just spotted your suggestion. If I'd seen it earlier, it would have helped me. I shall remember this, thank you! See my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure what the problem is in your case (I tested your snippet and it works as expected), but maybe this works for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo$ /redirect.html [redirect=temp,last]
```

I’m not an .htaccess expert, but I guess this would even be faster, because the `RewriteRule` pattern gets processed *before* `RewriteCond`.

Comment: That works, thanks. The problem was that I wanted to use RewriteRul in conjunction with RewriteCond (for more complex conditions), but as a workaround, I shall use your suggestion, amended as required. As you can confirm that yours is working correctly, I shall get hold of GoDaddy to find out what's happening on their end. Thank you.

Comment: I have discovered the problem, which seems to apply specifically to GoDaddy. I've added an answer to explain it.

Answer (score 3):

I have just discovered the solution! This seems to be a GoDaddy special.

Domains in GoDaddy are kept in subfolders; e.g. `mydomain.com` might be held in a subfolder called `md`.

Curiously, the start of `%{REQUEST_URI}` includes this string. Therefore, my RewriteCond should have read:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/md/foo$
```

It is not needed if the string does not necessarily start at the beginning. This explains my strange results.

I have edited my title to show that this applies specifically to GoDaddy, in the hope that this helps someone else.

Comment: Interesting! So `/md` doesn't actually appear in the URL you type in the address bar? It sounds like GoDaddy is doing an internal subrequest to this folder (is `REDIRECT_STATUS` set)!? Your .htaccess file is presumably in this subfolder? Just curious... what GoDaddy hosting package is this?

Comment: Apparently GoDaddy has updated its hosting package, and I'm still on the older one. I don't know how to check the value of `REDIRECT_STATUS`. To confirm, `/md` does not appear in the URL, only in the `%{REQUEST_URI}` within `.htaccess`. I wonder if I upgrade to the newer GoDaddy package (which is a lengthy process) if it would still happen.